# How to convert date format string to bool True and others to False?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas
import numpy
df=pandas.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c','b'],'col2':['N','2018-03-12 15:35',numpy.NaN,'2017-06-12 15:35'],'col3':['c','b','b','b']})
print(df)
```

Output of above script is:

```
  col1              col2 col3
0    a                 N    c
1    b  2018-03-12 15:35    b
2    c               NaN    b
3    b  2017-06-12 15:35    b
```

As to column `col2`,I want to convert all `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm` format string to bool `True`,others to `False`,keep `Na` value as same.
The expect result as below:

```
  col1              col2 col3
0    a             False    c
1    b              True    b
2    c               NaN    b
3    b              True    b
```

How to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create 2 masks - first convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)s with `errors='coerce'` and test [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and also test this column:

```
m1 = pd.to_datetime(df['col2'], errors='coerce').notna()
m2 = df['col2'].notna()
```

Then pass it to [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) - but is necessary convert `NaN` to `None`:

```
df['col2'] = np.select([m1, m2], [True, False], None)
print(df)
0    a  False    c
1    b   True    b
2    c   None    b
3    b   True    b
```

Or use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[m2, 'col2'] = m1
print(df)
  col1   col2 col3
0    a  False    c
1    b   True    b
2    c    NaN    b
3    b   True    b
```

Comment: what's `m1`,`m2` in the second method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
m=df.col2.notna()
df.loc[m,'col2']=(pd.to_datetime(df.col2.dropna(),errors='coerce').isna()
                                            .map({True:False,False:True}))
    print(df)
  col1   col2 col3
0    a  False    c
1    b   True    b
2    c    NaN    b
3    b   True    b
```